# Leading 0's missing from the data of csv file while using it in coded ui test

Tags: c#, csv, automated-tests, coded-ui-tests

I am using data from `csv` in data driven coded ui.

> In one of the columns(say "File Code") there are strings like 001,
>   abc123 etc.

I need to use the data of this column to search for results. But coded ui is not entering the leading 0's in the `TextBox`,instead,its just skipping the 0's and entering the latter part of the data.

> How can i make the test enter the 0's as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Coded UI reads CSV data in much the same way as Excel. It tries to infer the type of fields correctly. So fields that look like numbers, date and times are so interpreted.

One solution is to force a different interpretation. Possibilities include enclosing the field in double quotes or embedding a space.

Example:

```
Name,Number,Telephone
Alice,"001",01 234 567890
Brian,"002",01 234 678901
```